# GCM Error=MissingRegistration sending messages via JSON

Tags: android, json, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm testing push GCM via Fiddler

Headers:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Authorization: key=AIzaSyAkXfcuLLCZ-5n18wwO6XeJ13g-z9ja
Host: android.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 286
```

Body:

```
{"registration_ids":["APA91bHyn8YHcH_vSuOo7_A0PMgF5SU1K0FebOFGKXYTqpN5x4eD0tVBvzQLn749TVcczN5gSjB1wqf5AzYfxFI_qskA1Nzipf-9MfdEom1PI1vkFqKIg9B8vZvPLOLozE7jaRzELuyDzpFRbO3Xh5lT-KDA"],"collapse_key":"8b990f5a-78fc-4bad-b242-ffc740a750fb","data":{"message":"message to device"}}
```

I've got a error

```
Error=MissingRegistration
```

Where is my problem?
All ids are correct.

Comment: you should remove private data such as keys and secret id's

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You probably forgot to specify the content type in the header to be JSON.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

> If Content-Type is omitted, the format is assumed to be plain text.

And for plain text the registration ID is passed in a parameter called `registration_id` instead of `registration_ids`, which explains your `MissingRegistration` error.

Comment: In 2019 it still has sense!

Comment: @SatyajitBehera perhaps you have a different issue. I haven't worked with GCM for quite a few years, but this answer seems to still be helpful for some people (based on recent votes).

Answer (score 5):

For the new cloud Message, when you want to send a dwonstream message from the server, you need to use "to" to declaim the target registration id.

like below :

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx..."
}
```

Comment: So you must have the "to:..." if you want to send a push ? what if i want to send the push to all the users from a client ? (admin client for example..)

Answer (score 2):

For Firebase, You can get info from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes

> Check that the request contains a registration token (in the
>   registration_id in a plain text message, or in the to or
>   registration_ids field in JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
In my case receiver token was missing and after put the fcm receiver token its work fine for me
```