# GCM plain text Push notification in PHP?

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, plaintext

I am new In android and PHP. I am working on push Notification.
I have read many tutorials but all are for Json not for plain text.
For json code is here , but I want to send only plain text.
I have read this .

https://github.com/mattg888/GCM-PHP-Server-Push-Message/blob/master/GCMPushMessage.php

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

I have also read this .
[GCM Error=MissingRegistration sending messages via JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486192/gcm-error-missingregistration-sending-messages-via-json)

My code is here ,can some body help me in this

```
   <?php

$gcm_regid = 'fkjfsdhfsuvgsdhfkfkjshdfuwfsdfh9wfjehf9ufwjfhu9erfjkhf9efiefhwodfh9'; // GCM Registration ID
$registatoin_ids = array($gcm_regid);
$message = array("message" => "Hello test");


// Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $gcm_regid,
        'data' => 'helloword',
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=12dsdsvefdfdfgdfgdfgdfgfgfgfg',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to do plain text, you should ignore the context-type in this block

```
 $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=12dsdsvefdfdfgdfgdfgdfgfgfgfg',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );
```

Also, you should use for plain text the registration ID is passed in a parameter called `registration_id` instead of `registration_ids` array.